# python printing common items in a string without duplicating

Tags: python, string

I need to make a function that takes two string arguments and returns a string with only the characters that are in both of the argument strings. There should be no duplicate characters in the return value.

this is what I have but I need to make it print things only once if there  is more then one

```
def letter(x,z):
    for i in x:
        for f in z:
            if i == f:
                s = str(i)
                print(s)
```

Comment: Not sure if that'd belong more to Code Review...

Comment: @jmendeth Things only belong on Code Review if they're already working (which this apparently isn't)

Comment: To be clear are you returning something or are you printing something, or both?  And what language features can you use? (I get the impression that this is a homework problem)

Comment: BTW: `letter` isn't the best name for such an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s = set()

def letter(x,z):
    for i in x:
        for f in z:
            if i == f:
                s.add(i)


letter("hello","world")
print("".join(s))
```

It will print `'ol'`

Answer (score 5):

If the order is not important, you can take the intersection `&` of the `set` of characters in each word, then `join` that set into a single string and `return` it.

```
def makeString(a, b):
    return ''.join(set(a) & set(b))

>>> makeString('sentence', 'santa')
'nts'
```

Comment: also `''.join(set(a)).intersection(b)`

Comment: @gnibbler is `intersection` with a string more/less efficient?

Comment: @Cyber maybe you'd better started your answer with *Try this* ;-)

Comment: @Wolf The OP is still a beginner in python, else this answer is a hundred times better :)

Comment: @BhargavRao `this answer is a hundred times better` - that's just what I wanted to say! But - `still a beginner in python` - what a sharp eye! Your answer gave a better lexical match. :-)

Comment: @Wolf, `intersection` converts the seconds parameter to a set if it isn't already, so it's just a different way to say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If `set`s aren't your bag for some reason (perhaps you want to maintain  the order in one or other of the strings, try:

```
def common_letters(s1, s2):
    unique_letters = []
    for letter in s1:
        if letter in s2 and letter not in unique_letters:
            unique_letters.append(letter)

    return ''.join(unique_letters)

print(common_letters('spam', 'arthuprs'))
```

(Assuming Python 3 for the `print()`).

Comment: print() works fine in python 2.6 onwards .. and it's the 'right' way to do things to because it won't cause problems when converting from Python2 to Python3.